# Missing EOF at '@' in Eclipse Juno

Tags: html, css, eclipse, eof, xtext

I have been creating a website in eclipse recently and everything has been fine, however when I opened one of my CSS files I got prompted with 'Do you want to add xText nature to your project"... I clicked No.. however now all my css files have the same error at the @CHARSET "UTF-8" at the top of the file.

I have tried turning XText on and off through configure>>remove text nature but it does not fix the problem.

I have also tried creating new webpages in new workspaces but I still get an error every time I write @CHARSET in a CSS file.

Please help as I've ran out of ideas.

Comment: You could leave @CHARSET "UTF-8 out of the css as it is not needed, unless your are using unicode characters in your css (and even in that case I haven't really had a modern browser that could not handle it).

Comment: The CSS Editor from Eclipse WTP does not make use of XText.  Do you have the wrong editor set as the default on the File Associations preference page?